# Is there a way to write server side code on a unity photon cloud server

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have been looking for a way to write server side code on a public cloud unity photon server. Is there a way to do this without self hosting?

Comment: https://www.photonengine.com/pun
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Custom (game) server plugins are only available for Enterprise Cloud customers or self-hosted.